# Defining an interface, having operations, and Writing different classes to inherit those operations in Ballerina

Tags: oop, microservices, ballerina

I have a requirement to plug different types of classes based on some config(Sorry for the term. I mentioned this in java terminology).

This is  my use case.  I have a rest api service, and have the service implementation for that. Another implementation will be fronted by same rest APIs and swagger definition. But that service implementation will be based on some external engine.

In Java, we can define an interface, or abstract class and call those APIs, If we want to move  to a custom implementation, we can write a new class implementing that abstract class/interface and write the custom logic without changing the API definitions.

Is there any  similar approaches available ballerina to achieve this use case (plug multiple service implementations for a rest API).?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object type inclusion for this use case, for more info see https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/object-type-inclusion/

This sample has implemented the same use case but for datastores, https://github.com/ballerina-guides/gcp-microservices-demo/tree/main/cartservice